# TFS - "Could not find part of path" error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I'm getting this error after completely re-organizing the project's folder structure. I'm guessing there's a lot. I get this error when trying to check in or promote the changes.

Answer (score 44):

The error you have is mainly caused when you're trying to check in files which is no longer exist on the machine.

To resolve it, go to Source Control  Explorer -> select these missing files -> **Undo Pending Changes**. Or you can just left these files in the **Excluded Changes** list to not checking them.

Comment: The file is there

Comment: Still relevant answer almost 7 years later. Thanks.

Comment: Although the answer makes sense, this still seems like really 'buggy' behavior on the part of Microsoft VS.  My guess is that packages were added somewhere, deleted, the add was 'detected' but the delete was not 'detected', and the pending changes are in an unstable state.  Really Microsoft VS should keep track of this stuff.