# TFS Could not find a part of the path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to check in a project for my repository in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), but I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

The `Z:` is second HD in my notebook.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18750781/447156 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/31845830/447156?

Comment: Vote to close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750781/tfs-checkin-error-could-not-find-file

Comment: Is the FoxCcoManagerDatabase.sln file existing?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Thanks, is this.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Could you reproduce this issue with a new project? What's the result if you create a new workspace (delete old one) and map to that path, then check in?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. What I did was to look for those entries in the Source Control Explorer and just remove them (Delete).

I compiled again and tried again to submit my changes and worked perfectly.